# Выбор строк из Dataframe по нескольким критериям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как из DataFrame выбрать строки полностью совпадающие (индексы могут не совпадать) со строками из другого DataFrame?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"A":['a','b','c'], "B":[1,2,3], "C":[2,6,7]}
data2 = {"A":['b','a','c'], "B":[0,1,9], "C":[2,2,27]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# выбираем из df строки, которые есть в df2 (возможно с другим индексом)
lf = {"A":df2["A"], "B":df2["B"], "C":df2["C"]}
f = df[list(lf)].isin(lf).all(axis=1)
df[f]
```

Результат:

```
A   B   C
```

должно быть:

```
    A   B   C
0   a   1   2
```

Сейчас проверка условия идет в df2 только в строке с таким же индексом, а нужно, чтобы проверялась вся таблица, т.к. искомая строка может быть в другом месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного дополню [ответ @Dementiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/846498/211923).

`df1.merge(df2)` по умолчанию использует все столбцы с одинаковыми наименованиями для объединения. Т.е. для следующих DF:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 'B': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'C': {0: 2, 1: 6, 2: 7}})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'b', 1: 'a', 2: 'c', 3: 'c'},'B': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 9, 3: 7},'C': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 27, 3: 7}})

In [22]: d1
Out[22]:
   A  B  C
0  a  1  2
1  b  2  6
2  c  3  7

In [23]: d2
Out[23]:
   A  B   C
0  b  0   2
1  a  1   2
2  c  9  27
3  c  7   7
```

следующий вызов будет использовать все три столбца `['A','B','C']` для объединения:

```
In [24]: d1.merge(d2)
Out[24]:
   A  B  C
0  a  1  2
```

можно явно указать "связующие" столбцы:

```
In [25]: d1.merge(d2, on=['A','B'], suffixes=['','_2'])
Out[25]:
   A  B  C  C_2
0  a  1  2    2

In [26]: d1.merge(d2, on=['A','C'], suffixes=['','_2'])
Out[26]:
   A  B  C  B_2
0  a  1  2    1
1  c  3  7    7
```

если наименования столбцов отличаются:

```
In [29]: d1.merge(d2, left_on=['A','C'], right_on=['A','B'], suffixes=['','_2'])
Out[29]:
   A  B  C  B_2  C_2
0  c  3  7    7    7
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что имеется ввиду под *несколькими критериями*. Если хочется выбрать просто одинаковые строки, вне зависимости от того сколько раз они повторяются, то можно использовать [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), например:

```
>>> data1 = {"A":['a','b','c','b'], "B":[1,2,3,0], "C":[2,6,7,2]}
>>> data2 = {"A":['b','a','c'], "B":[0,1,9], "C":[2,2,27]}
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
   A  B  C
0  a  1  2
1  b  0  2
```

Comment: Несколько критериев - в данном случае это значения в колонках 'A', 'B', и 'C', но может быть и вариант только с двумя, например: lf = {"A":df2["A"], "C":df2["C"]} - тогда ваше решение  не подойдет, как я понимаю.